# Hide sibling divisions based on click event

Tags: jquery

I've divisions like

```
<div id="divFirst"></div>
<div id="divSecond"></div>
<div id="divThid"></div>
<div id="Fourth"></div>
```

I've four buttons "First,Second,Third & Fourth". Whenever I click any button, the respective div should get displayed and the others should get hide.. I'm trying using siblings hide..

```
var selected = this.name;
$('#'+selected).show('slow').siblings().hide('slow')
```

;

Thank you.
Nizam

Comment: Posted..added in the message

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/4bJjc/3/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your selector is wrong (assuming the names of the buttons are simply `First`, `Second`, etc).

Try updating the code as follows:

```
$('#div'+selected).show('slow').siblings('div').hide('slow');
```

Of course, you'll need to update the ID of your fourth `<div>` element to include the `div` prepended string:

```
<div id="divFourth"></div>
```

Also, your third `<div>` has a typo (see `divThid`, should be `divThird`).

Here's a [**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5d7CH/).

Comment: I was editing the answer while you were commenting :)

Comment: Not really. I was just too lazy to format that line of code. Sue me :P

Comment: `$('#div'+selected).show('slow').siblings('div').hide('slow');`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to you use a wrapper div for those and define a class for click event access to all divs or use wrapper > child selector.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('#wrapper > div').click(function(){
        $(this).show().siblings().toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

**HTML**

```
<div id="buttons">
    <button name="divFirst">A</button>
    <button name="divSecond">B</button>
    <button name="divThird">C</button>
    <button name="divFourth">D</button>
</div>
<div id="divs">
    <div id="divFirst" class="hide">A</div>
    <div id="divSecond" class="hide">B</div>
    <div id="divThird" class="hide">C</div>
    <div id="divFourth" class="hide">D</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hide{
    display:none;
}
.show{
    display:block;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('#buttons button').click(function(){
    var selected = $(this).attr('name');
    $('#divs div').attr({class:'hide'});
    $('#' + selected).attr({class:'show'});
});
```